# Is Live Agent possible with Leads and the Sales Console?

Tags: case, leads, liveagent, omnichannel

We are planning to use Live Agent, but have a scenario where Sales is intending to use Live Agent with Leads and where Service is using Live Agent with Cases.

Is that possible?

Would that involve two chatbuttons and two omnichannel configurations, one for Leads and one for Cases?

Answer (score 3):

I guess Live agent does not support Sales objects but lightning powered live chat version does work ...it's called "Snap In"... there are lot of documents how to implement it...

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/snapins.pdf

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=snapins_chat_overview.htm&type=5